# Gcm unregistration

Tags: android, asynchronous, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on GCM in android. 
I am done with the registration of the device with GCM by using following code which registers the device asynchronously.

```
private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                    msg="Registration success. Regid: "+regid;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Log.e("GCM", msg);
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

registration is done in registrationActivity
Now i want to unregister the device.
Unregister command is sent by the server app, which is received on android side.
How can i unregister the device from the activity (mdmActivity) where i process the received messages. 
Whether it should be asyn or sync??

Is it wrong to create an object for registrationActivity and calling a unregisterInBackground function using that object as below from mdmActivity?

```
 RegistrationActivity reg=new RegistrationActivity();
 reg.unregisterInBackground();
```

And the unregisterInBackground function in registrationActivity is as follows:

```
protected void unregisterInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    gcm.unregister();
                    msg = "Device unregistered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // delete the regID 
                    deleteRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Log.e("unregistration", msg);
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Need your help!! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`unregister()` is also blocking, like `register()`. As such, you really need to run it in a background thread similar to the way you did with an AsyncTask.

You call it on the GCM instance, so I think it's fine to call it from whichever activity as long as you have that `gcm` instance.

You might want to read [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#unreg) before implementing the unregister functionality.